# Failed to read key myapp from store (Prjoect imorted)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

I imported an android studio project from another developer to my system while generating Signed APK I am getting this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key mobile_visit_confirmation from store "C:\Users\ABC\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\myapp_Key_Store.jks":
    Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

The project was done by someone now I am working on that he is not providing password, alias and certificate information and I want to upload update APK to play store.

Comment: is app already published on playstore?

Comment: @akhilesh0707 yes

Comment: you need to create your own `release.keystore`

Comment: then you cannot update your app using new `keystore `

Comment: you need  that keystore file or create new from android studio

Comment: try this link http://techzog.com/development/retrieve-saved-keystore-password-android-studio/

Comment: http://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/

Comment: Previously the app is developed on the same machine you are working on right now?

Comment: i created new keystore but google restrict me to add updated apk to server @akhilesh0707

Comment: with new keystore you cannot update the previously published app,